# Spring boot + data JPA : properties of joined entities not fetched

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I used Spring web MVC + data JPA so far and I could write integration tests with H2 fine.
Now I am using Spring Boot and I have a strange behaviour when trying to use H2 in my integration tests. I have a following 2 entities (using lombok too):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT_LIFE")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class EventLifeEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID")
    private TaskEntity taskEntity;

    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ORDR")
    private Integer order;

    @Column(name = "COMMAND")
    private String command;

    ...
}
```

When I try to convert the entity to DO I get a NullpointerException as only the id of Task is set, all the other properties are null. I am in the same transaction when the conversion happens so the properties should be loaded. Anyway I tried to get the 'order' property of Task before calling the converter class but it is null.

```
@Service
public class RepositoryErrorSourceService implements ErrorSourceService {

    ....

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String search(Event event) {
        ...
        EventLife eventLife = EventLife.builder()
                                       .date(Calendar.getInstance())
                                       .event(eventToDomainConverter.convert(eventEntity))
                                       .task(command)
                                       .eventStatus(EventStatusEnum.BEFORE_START)
                                       .order(0).build();
        EventLifeEntity eventLifeEntity = eventLifeEntityRepository.save( eventLifeToEntityConverter.convert(eventLife) );
        LOGGER.debug("The following EvenEntity is saved: {}", eventLifeEntity);
        // starting the first task of the workflow
        command.execute( eventLifeToDomainConverter.convert( eventLifeEntity) );
        ...
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    providedRuntime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.191'
    testCompile 'com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.9.0'   
}
```

So I used fine H2 in my integration tests but it seems that I am missing something at spring boot. It is also possible that I've forgotten about a setting somewhere. Either way I am stuck.
If anybody could help me that would be splendid!

Thanks,
V.

+++++++++++++++++ UPDATE 1 ++++++++++++++++
Forgot to mention but I tried with eager fetch type too. I even tried to refer to the specific property before calling the converter but no change.

Comment: You don't need to specifie the version of hsql db. runtime('com.h2database:h2') should be enough as spring manages the versions by itself. I had a similiar problem with in memory DB. Try using runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb') and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks Dennis but no change I am afraid. V.

Comment: Possibly try an eager fetch type?

Comment: Hi Collin, I've forgotten to put it above but I tried it with eager too. I even tried to refer to the specific property before the conversion but no difference. However I am in the transaction so the entity manager should be able to cope.

Comment: Any idea? I think it is somehow connected to Spring Boot. Perhaps I miss a configuration somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I have the same issue with mysql. :( the same converter is used in my project but when I use it in my Runnable class then not all the fields but only the id of the relating entities are fetched. Any idea?